# Try except not catching FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, try-catch

I'm trying to catch the FileNotFoundError and break the code when it occurs, but for some reason it's not working, im still getting the error and the code is not breaking, here is my code

```
file_name = input("Choose a file: ")
def split_columns(file_name):
    x_values = []
    y_values = []     
    try:                                            
        with open(file_name) as f:
            for line in f:
                row_values = line.split()
                print(row_values)
                x_values.append(float(row_values[0]))
                y_values.append(float(row_values[1]))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('This file does not exist, try again!')
        raise
    return x_values, y_values
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: `raise` means that the error will be explicitly thrown even though you are catching it. You are throwing the error which is why you are still getting it. You are not doing anything that will allow the user to try again. There's no loop in this code that waits until a correct file is chosen. There is a loop but it is inside the exception so if the exception happens that loop will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the `try/except` out of the function, and put it in the loop that calls the function.

```
def split_columns(file_name):
    x_values = []
    y_values = []     
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            row_values = line.split()
            print(row_values)
            x_values.append(float(row_values[0]))
            y_values.append(float(row_values[1]))
    return x_values, y_values

while True:
    file_name = input("Choose a file: ")
    try:
        x_values, y_values = split_columns(file_name)
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('This file does not exist, try again!')
```